# RStudio keeps loading prior session with no files and wont run commands

Tags: r, rstudio

Rstudio keeps opening the same three files that I had opened before. Some strange things include:

1. Able to close the files just fine, but can't run any of the code. R just gets stuck.
2. Don't have any Files, plots, packages
3. Whenever closing or restarting R, it just gets stuck infinitely in the attached picture (I always have to force quit)
4. Whats stranger is I can start a New Session and all of a sudden everything works normally in the new session (e.g. files, packages is populated; can open/save/closeout and end the session) however the old session is still unusable and I have to force quit when I'm done.

[image]

Comment: Try killing RStudio, renaming the directory mentioned in https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State, and re-starting

Comment: Did you try removing ~/.RData ?

Comment: Hey, how you solve this problem?