# Viewing the deleted source code of an R script that is currently executing

Tags: r, rstudio

I believe that I am experiencing the same issue as the fella in this question: [How to prevent objects from automatically loading when I open Rstudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33074305/how-to-prevent-objects-from-automatically-loading-when-i-open-rstudio)

In short, when I opened RStudio, the old code from this morning popped up and then saved, overwriting hours of work. Unlike Microsoft Office, I don't see an option for Rstudio to recover a lost file retroactively. In my search, I did change my Global auto-save option to "Backup Unsaved Changes". That doesn't help now.

I will be adding an answer of my own of how I recovered my work, but if there's a better, proactive solution, I'm all ears and can share necessary info.

Comment: "In short, when I opened RStudio, the old code from this morning popped up and then saved, overwriting hours of work." I don't really understand the description of your issue. Does that mean an old history was saved over a saved script? I strongly suggest that you commit to git frequently, which would mitigate such issues.

Comment: My work is typically a bunch of custom scripts to do small, specific things. Today it was a meta-summary script that is actually still running. My supervisor said we'll be moving to "each project a repository", but our current workflow is reporting results and then methods when and where requested.

Comment: Create a personal repository for your scripts. It could even be local on your PC.

Comment: Good, general purpose, proactive advice

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR If there are session directories in `/.local/share/rstudio/sources/`, then your lost file is inside one the sessions' `*-contents` files.

My first googling brought me [here](https://docs.posit.co/ide/user/ide/guide/environments/r/managing-r.html) where I found `R.home(component = "home")` to navigate me to the my R's install directory. There are a few versions of R installed on this system. However, that was a bust, as there were no relevant startup files that appeared to either be the culprit of my issue, or my solution to my lost work.

Some more searching landed me on this question:

[RStudio keeps loading prior session with no files and wont run commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58681060/rstudio-keeps-loading-prior-session-with-no-files-and-wont-run-commands)

...whose comment pointed me [here](https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State) where I could see that `~/.local/share/rstudio` is another clue to follow, and it was! While I have my home .RHistory, this directory has a spare copy with timestamps called `history_database`, allowing me to see the interactive work I did in Rstudio.

But the most important part was the script I wrote, sent off to run and then lost it. Thankfully, in `/.local/share/rstudio/sources/` there was a `session*` directory with files with a timestamp matching the time I started the script. The files in that directory are named as 8-digit hex values, and for each there is a `*-contents` files which contains the script that is being ran!

Unfortunately, it doesn't keep a record of the sourced files that go along with it, but that's better than remembering what I did and fumbling about trying to recreate some of my, let's say, creative work.